# Android: How to execute shell command 'rm' in app

Tags: android, shell

I can easily use 'rm /data/system/[file]' from adb shell but from app this is not working.

Commands 'du', 'ls', 'echo' works fine from code but command 'rm' is not working. It is not even working on sdcard.

Code I have tried:

1)

```
String[] cmd = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "rm -r /sdcard/1" }; 
    try {

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);//execute command

        //read the output of command
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()); 
.....
```

2) Same code as (1), with "su" instead of "/system/bin/sh"

3)

```
process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("rm -r /sdcard/1\n");
os.flush();
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
process.waitFor();
```

4) Same code as (3), with 'su' instead of '/system/bin/sh'

Comment: Have tried to use `delete` ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete%28java.nio.file.Path%29

Comment: java.nio.file.Files is not appearing to be accessible. I tried the java.io.File, but its delete function i snot working.

Comment: Is your app owner of the file?

Comment: No, its not. Its a system file, from '/data/system/'. Can not root allow to access this dir?

Comment: I don't think it works that way. If it could, your app could destroy the complete system, which is not a good idea.

Comment: yeah, but from 'adb shell' same commands work, should not they work form code too

Comment: No. `adb shell` is a development tool, which only works if USB debugging is switched on. Don't rely on that setting.

Answer (score 0):

go to the boot setting in developers mode,debug it with .anr file ,then compile inertpreteor with dex file to start booting the rm command

Answer (score 0):

You can **remove** files inside your ***app field structure***

I mean: **/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp**

[I'm not sure if you can remove files else where, because of **sudo** needed]

So, just go for like:

```
String cmd="rm -f /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/myfile.txt";
try
  {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh","-c",cmd});
  }
  catch(Exception e){}
```

- **-f** to force the remove [optional]
- the exception {} is up to you